# jquery drop down question

Tags: jquery, html, show-hide

ok heres the main idea of code

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td id="ddFish"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
<div id="ddRegion">
    <div id="North"></div>
</div>
<div id="nec">
    <div id="necArea"></div>
</div>
<div id="area1"></div>
```

i need jquery script that does the following... i cant for the life of me figure it out

when the td #ddFish hover, show #ddRegion.

when #North hover, show #nec.

when #necArea hover, show #area1

let me know if there are other questions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do for every element pair:

```
$('#elementID1').mouseover(function() {
    $('#elementID2').show();
});
```

Or more dynamic:

```
var map = {
    '#ddFish': '#ddRegion',
    '#North': '#nec',
    '#necArea': '#area1'
}

for(var source in map) {
    $(source).mouseover((function(target) {
        return function() {
            $(target).show();
        };
    }(map[source])));
}
```

Working [**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/zcTrL/) - as karim already said, you have to add the code to the `ready` event handler.

Comment: thats what i tried... not working. i have decent exp with show hide function but its not working.. i thought maybe there was another way to write it?

Comment: @Alex - are you binding your handlers when the DOM is ready? This should work. Based on your markup, the only feasible way to do this is to bind a handler to one ID and reveal another one. @Felix - I'm all outta votes :(

Comment: @Felix: mousover --> mouseover :)

Comment: @karim79: I hit the limit already, so it does not matter ;) :o) I appreciate your imaginary upvote :)

Comment: hmm i think it was my jquery 1.3.2 vs the newer 1.4.2.. i sourced that in and it works.. but now it seems some other elements are scattered a bit  uuuggghhh

Comment: @Alex: Not sure. Works also with `1.3.2` for me (even `1.2.6`).